# Connecting a HTML link to an API page

Tags: html, django, hyperlink, django-rest-framework

I have a working HTML view and a working detail API RUD view for some simple model objects. Within the HTML view, elements are listed that have their own API RUD view. I'd like to be able to link each list element in the HTML to it's own API RUD view.

Below is my models.py:

```
class Hints(models.Model):

    text = models.TextField(max_length=255)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.text)

    def timestamp_pretty(self):
        return self.timestamp.strftime('%b %d %Y')

    def get_api_url(self, request=None):
        return api_reverse("api-hints1:hints-rud", kwargs={'pk': self.pk}, request=request)
```

Below is my views.py:

```
class HTMLAPIView(viewsets.ViewSet):
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'base.html'
    serializer_class = HTMLSerializer


    def list(self, request):
        queryset = Hints.objects.order_by('pk')
        paginator = Paginator(queryset, 5) # Show 5 items per page
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        queryset1 = paginator.get_page(page)

        return Response({'queryset1': queryset1})


class HintsListApiView(mixins.CreateModelMixin, generics.ListAPIView):

    lookup_field = 'pk'
    serializer_class = HintsSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Hints.objects.all()
        query = self.request.GET.get("q")
        if query is not None:
            qs = qs.filter(
                Q(text__icontains=query)|
                Q(author__icontains=query)
                ).distinct()
        return qs

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_serializer_context(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return {"request": self.request}


class HintsRudView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):

    lookup_field = 'pk'
    serializer_class = HintsSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Hints.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_context(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return {"request": self.request}
```

My urls.py:

```
from .views import HintsRudView, HintsListApiView, HTMLAPIView
from . import views
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework import routers, serializers, viewsets

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)$', HintsRudView.as_view(), name='hints-rud'),
    url(r'^$', HintsListApiView.as_view(), name='hints-list'),
    url(r'^html/', HTMLAPIView.as_view({'get': 'list'}), name='html' )    
]
```

And my relevant HTML code: 
As you can see this was my attempt `<li><a href="{% url 'hints-rud' pk=pk %}">{{ query }}</a></li>`. Unfortunately, I get the following error:

> Reverse for 'hints-rud' not found. 'hints-rud' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'hints1/style.css' %}"> 
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One|Montserrat|Noto+Serif|Nunito|Oswald|Teko" rel="stylesheet"> 
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Handy Dev Hints</h1>

    <ul>
        {% for query in queryset1 %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'hints-rud' pk=pk %}">{{ query }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

<br/>
<br/>

<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        <center>
        {% if queryset1.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page=1">&laquo; First</a>
            <a href="?page={{ queryset1.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        {% if queryset1.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ queryset1.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
            <a href="?page={{ queryset1.paginator.num_pages }}">Last &raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
        <br/>
        <br/>
            <span class="current">
                Page {{ queryset1.number }} of {{ queryset1.paginator.num_pages }}
            </span>
        </center>
    </span>
</div>

</body>   
</html>
```

Not sure where to go from here. This doesn't seem like it should be a difficult problem. I've tried removing some `$` from the `urls.py` but it made little difference. I've also tried other views and patterns besides `hints-rud` but all come back with the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the namespace, exactly as you do in the `get_api_url` method.

```
<a href="{% url 'api-hints1:hints-rud' pk=pk %}">
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel! Yes that makes sense. Upon performing this I am presented with the following error.


> Reverse for 'hints-rud' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['api/hints/(?P<pk>\\d+)$']

I have tried a few approaches such as `pk=hints.pk` and `pk=self.pk`, but arrive at the same error.

Comment: Presumably you want the pk of the element in the queryset you're iterating through, so it would be `query.pk`.

Comment: Indeed! Thank you so much. And it makes sense which is the best part.